# Windows (XP, Vista, 7) - Disable prompt to format unknown partitions

Tags: windows, filesystems, windows-registry, partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable “you need to format this disk” message in Windows Vista/7?](https://superuser.com/questions/49382/how-do-i-disable-you-need-to-format-this-disk-message-in-windows-vista-7)

I use external hard disks a lot, and sometimes they are formatted as disk types that Windows does not recognize (ie: anything other than FAT/NTFS). Every time I leave the disk plugged in, Windows provides me with a prompt every time it attempts to auto-mount the disk. ie:

> "The following disk uses an unrecognized partition type or is not
>   formatted. Would you like to format it now?"

I always click no, but on one unfortunate occasion, I accidentally hit enter (nice going Microsoft, default to blast away a drive with unknown partition type for me).

Is there a way to tell Windows to stop nagging me about unformatted or unrecognized drives?

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, are you intending to try to write a device driver or other application to resolve this problem, or did you just want to know if there was already a known solution?

Comment: I am not attempting to write a device driver. I just want to disable the system dialogs and pop-up notifications that Windows gives my every time the drive is detected by Windows, offering me to format the drive. I don't want to format it, and I want Windows to stop asking me to format it.