# Do not mount certain partitions

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, mount

I have an external hard drive that has Ubuntu installed on certain partitions. Whenever I connect it to my main PC, Windows attempts to mount two of the partitions, which are `ext4` filesystems. So, it is unable to mount them, and I receive the "Do you want to format this disk?" window.

Is there a way to prevent Windows for attempting to mount these specific partitions of the hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

The most common suggestion is to put a tiny FAT32 partition on it. That way, Windows recognizes *something*, instead of thinking it's a blank disk.

Also see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/598644/how-can-i-prevent-windows-8-from-trying-to-format-my-external-ext3-format-hard-d).