# Get ID of partition in Diskpart

Tags: windows, partitioning, diskpart

In `diskpart`, the `setid` command can "change the partition type".

How can I check what ID was set with `setid`? There is no command called `getid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the command `detail partition` displays that after `Type:`

Comment: Pretty sure that's the ID for the type of partition, not the GUID of the partition itself

Comment: @Xebozone Makes sense. The question says "partition type", not "GUID". Thanks for pointing out that these two things shouldn't be confused.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a bit too late & redundant now.

However:

```
list disk
Sel disk
list part
sel part
detail part
```

in my case it showed

```
DISKPART> detail part

Partition 1
Type  : 84
Hidden: Yes
Active: No
Offset in Bytes: 1048576
```