# Prevent Windows 11 from ever asking what to do with a newly attached drive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-11, user-interface

When I attach a new, unformatted drive to my Windows 11 VM, it keeps asking whether I want to format the drive, in order to use it.

That question is superfluous, as I'm actually mounting a RasPi and I'm using a flash tool to handle that.

I'd like to prevent windows from asking what to do when a drive is attached.
How do I do that?

I don't want this to be specific to a certain volume, I just want to prevent Windows from asking about what to do with unformatted drives in general.

Comment: Have you tried? https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-11/how-to-enable-disable-autoplay-on-windows-11/td-p/2764768

Comment: @Gantendo thanks. I'd never have guessed it's an "Auto Play" feature. I disabled Auto Play and it seems to solve the issue.

Comment: For the record, the question mark should've been at the end of that comment. My bad.

Comment: @Gantendo I disabled Auto Play as described in the tech forum, disabling Auto Play in general by that toggle switch at the top left. Yet, when I attach a RasPi to the VM, it still asks whether to format the drive *some times*, but not always. It seems Windows is confused, whether the drive is a removable drive like a memory card, or a hard drive that has been hot-swapped. Either way, I'd love to disable it in general, if required by editing Registry manually...

Comment: https://www.ghacks.net/2017/11/09/block-you-need-to-format-the-disk-message-in-windows/ & 
https://superuser.com/questions/49382/how-do-i-disable-you-need-to-format-this-disk-message-in-windows-vista-7 Windows is *always* confused, but this might be a workaround.