# How to disable the popup "You need to format the disk in drive..." in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, sd-card

Creating OS images for a device, every time I plug the SD card, it triggers this pop-up for each of the unknown partitions.

After flashing the SD, it triggers those 10-12 pop-ups again.

And this, again and again during my daily work.

[image]

Removing the SD does not hide/close the pop-ups either.

I just want to disable this feature on Windows. The following thread [How do I disable "you need to format this disk" message in Windows Vista/7?](https://superuser.com/questions/49382/how-do-i-disable-you-need-to-format-this-disk-message-in-windows-vista-7) explains how to disable it for a specific drive, but as I am flashing that drive all the time, it's not a solution.

**How to disable this popup definitively on Windows 10?**

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried to disable AutoPlay?
If you go into "Settings" > "Devices" > "Auto Play" and disable "Auto Play for all Media and devices" should prevent any popups from appearing when mounting devices.

Answer (score 1):

This message is sometimes dangerous if one accidentally formats a disk
that shouldn't be formatted, such as as an encrypted drive.

Unfortunately, Windows will always access any newly inserted disk,
in order to find its attributes for display in Disk Management.

The only sure way to disable the device is in the BIOS.

Comment: How to disable the device in the BIOS but still have access to it?

Comment: Unfortunately that's impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Try from command prompt (Admin):

```
mountvol /n [enter]

mountvol /r [enter]
```

A reboot may be required.

For external drives that should get a drive letter, assign drive letters now using Disk Management.

To enable automatic mounting again at some point do

```
mountvol /e [enter]
```

Reboot.

Comment: `automount` is not recognized as command in both powershell and cmd.

Comment: automount seems to be a sub-command of `diskpart`

Comment: This is not working: I get those popup after restarting the computer.

Comment: my mistake, corrected.

Comment: The solution with `mountvol` unfortunately has no effect. I also checked the key in the registry (it's set) but has no effect. All drives are still mounted and those pop-up appear.

Comment: Weird. I ran into same issue while imaging flash drives that 'drop' (see https://youtu.be/3Euh4eD_x-Y). Mountvol solved it for me. You can try with DiskPart as that affects both basic and other partition layouts where mountvol supposedly only has effect with devices with basic partitions.

Comment: I must add I'm on Windows 10 though, maybe that makes a difference.